# Knowing Feature Importance from Sparse Matrix

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, feature-selection

I was working with a dataset that had a textual column as well as numerical columns, so I used `TFIDF` for the textual column and created a sparse matrix, similarly for the numerical features I created a sparse matrix using `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` and combined them with the text sparse features.

Then I'm feeding the algorithm to a gradient boosting model and doing the rest of the training and prediction.
However I want to know, is there any way I can plot the feature importance, of this sparse matrix and will be able to know the important feature column names?

Answer (score 1):

You would have a map of your features from the TFIDF map.

```
column_names_from_text_features = vectorizer.vocabulary_
rev_dictionary = {v:k for k,v in vectorizer.vocabulary_.items()}
column_names_from_text_features = [v for k,v in rev_dictionary.items()]
```

Since you know the column names of your other features, the entire list of features you pass to XGBoost (after the `scipy.hstack`) could be

```
all_columns = column_names_from_text_features + other columns
```

(or depending on the order in which you horizontally stacked)

Now, once you run the XGBoost Model, you can use the [plot_importance](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.plotting) function for feature importance. Your code would look something like this:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier, plot_importance
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 8))
plot_importance(<xgb-classifier>, max_num_features = 15, xlabel='F-score', ylabel='Features', ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

These features would be labeled fxxx, fyyy etc where xxx and yyy are the indices of the features passed to xgboost.

Using the `all_columns` constructed in the first part, you could map the features to in indices in the plot encoding.